# ¿como puedo llenar de datos mis tablas, ya que todas menos 1(tb_carrera) poseen llaves foraneas?

Tags: php, mysql

```
Create database proyectoweb;
use proyectoweb;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_carrera;
CREATE TABLE tb_carrera (
id_carrera int not null auto_increment,
Nombre nvarchar(50) not null,
constraint pk_1 primary key(id_carrera)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_docentes;
CREATE TABLE tb_docentes (
id_docente int not null auto_increment,
Nombre nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
id_carrera int ,
Rol nvarchar (30) not null,
Contraseña nvarchar(8) not null,
Estatus tinyint,
constraint pk_2 primary key  (id_docente),
constraint fk_1 foreign key (id_carrera) references tb_carrera(id_carrera)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_prospecto;
CREATE TABLE tb_prospecto (
id_prospecto INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
Telefono nvarchar(10) NOT NULL,
Correo nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
id_carrera int ,
Modalidad nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,
Estatus tinyint,
Comentario nvarchar(100),
Fecha datetime,
constraint pk_3 primary key (id_prospecto),
constraint fk_2 foreign key (id_carrera) references tb_carrera(id_carrera)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_asignacion;
CREATE TABLE tb_asignacion (
folio int not null auto_increment,
id_prospecto int ,
id_docente int ,
constraint pk_4 primary key  (folio),
constraint fk_3 foreign key (id_prospecto) references tb_prospecto(id_prospecto)
on update cascade
on delete cascade,
constraint fk_4 foreign key (id_docente) references tb_docentes(id_docente)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tb_seguimiento;
CREATE TABLE tb_seguimiento (
consecutivo int not null auto_increment,
fecha datetime,
folio int ,
acccion nvarchar(20) not null,
comentarios nvarchar (100),
constraint pk_5 primary key  (consecutivo),
constraint fk_5 foreign key (folio) references tb_asignacion(folio)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

insert into tb_carrera (Nombre) values ('Tecnologias de la informacion y cominicacion');
insert into tb_carrera (Nombre) values ('Administracion');
insert into tb_carrera (Nombre) values ('Procesos Alimentarios');
insert into tb_carrera (Nombre) values ('Paramedico');
insert into tb_carrera (Nombre) values ('Lengua unglesa');


insert into tb_prospecto (Nombre,Telefono,Correo, id_carrera,Modalidad,Estatus,Comentario)  values ('Pablo garcia perez', '7353972275','bions55@hotmail.com',2,'Despresuarizado',1,'Hola como estas');
insert into tb_prospecto (Nombre,Telefono,Correo,Modalidad,Estatus,Comentario,Fecha)  values ('Luis  Soriano perez', '7353972275','S0us1d3@hotmail.com','Despresuarizado',2,'Cuanto cuesta una inscrpcion');
insert into tb_prospecto (Nombre,Telefono,Correo,Modalidad,Estatus,Comentario,Fecha)  values ('Pako  garcia Soriano', '7353972275','Kanashimi@hotmail.com','Escolarizado',1,'Hola mi amor');u
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

En tu Script coloca despues del `use proyectoweb;`

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

y que la última instrucción del script sea

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Tomado originalmente de [How to temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-to-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)